# Converting base 10 fractions into other bases

Tags: arithmetic, number-systems

How do you convert

$14\frac{8}{13}$

into base 3?

I was able to convert $\frac{3}{7}$ into base 3 by constantly multiplying by 3 and dividing the numerator by denominator until I finally got a repetition, but this method doesn't seem to work for $14\frac{8}{13}$.

The correct answer is supposed to be $112.\overline{121}_{3}$

Comment: Um, fractions work the same in all bases. There's an integer above the fraction bar and an integer below. You can write those integers in any basis you like; doing that is independent of the fact that they're in a fraction.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand, are you saying I can just convert the top number and the bottom number seperately?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see the supposed correct answer. I was confused because you described the input as a "base 10 fraction", and the equivalent of that in base 3 would be $\left[112\frac{22}{111}\right]_3$. You can do long division $22\div 111$ in base 3 to get the positional notation.

Comment: Thanks for that, so I can convert the 14 seperately to the $\frac{8}{13}$ since they are just two numbers multiplied

Comment: Oops, yes, I meant added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just like you convert a fraction to decimal.  $8\cdot 3=24=13(1)+11,$ so the first digit (ternit?) is $1. \ \  11\cdot 3=33=13(2)+7,$ so the second digit is $2. \ \  3\cdot 7=21=13(1)+8$ and so on.  I get $112.\overline{121}_{3}$

Alternately you can notice that $\frac{8}{13}=\frac{16}{3^3-1}$, so the repeat is $3$ digits long and is $16_{10}=121_3$

Comment: Is your answer only for $\frac{8}{3}$?

Comment: Thanks, no worries, I am able to convert the 14 into base 3, I didn't know you were supposed to do the 14 and the fraction separately.

Comment: @Arvin:  I was only describing how to do the fraction, $\frac{8}{13}$, not $\frac{8}{3}$.  I then appended the result for the whole number (now corrected to $112_3$)

Comment: Typo, I meant to write $\frac{8}{13}$. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You convert 8 and 13 into base 3, and do a long division in that base,

```
          0.202           8 = 101
      ------------           -----
  111 ) 101              13 = 111
         22.2
         -----
          1.100
          0.222
            101  (repeats on three places)
```

So the answer is 112.202 202 202

Comment: $8=22_3$ so $22_3/111_3=0.121121...$